# Using the non SSL URL from project properties in Visual Studio ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, ssl

I'm trying to see if there is a way to access my site without turning off SSL?

So in the project properties window I see two URL's, one SSL one without!

[image]

Can't I use the non SSL URL to connect to a controller's action method?

What is this non SSL URL used for?

Comment: You need to tell us what happens when you try to connect to `http://localhost:50064` instead of `https://localhost:44368`.

Comment: It says "can't reach this page" in the browser and then url switches to https

Comment: What is the actual error? Is it failing to make a TCP connection? Does the server return an error response (404? 500? something else?) What does your browser's Web Inspector's Network tab say?

Comment: there's no error number. It just says status 'failed' in the network area of the chrome debugger and in the browser it says "error connection refused"

Comment: I don't really know if this http url is for connecting to the site as http? I'm unfamiliar and kinda a newbie to SSL